# Extended classes, function definitions with type hinting & strict warnings

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm attempting maintenance work on a relatively large Zend codebase and part of the work included ugprading from php 5.3 to php 5.6.

Having set `error_reporting = E_ALL`, I'm seeing these notices on 
nearly every page of the site:

```
PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of <child::method()> should be compatible 
with <parent::method()>
```

I've created a contrived example that demonstrates the issue:

```
cat > doStuff.php <<"EOF"
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('Potato.php');
require_once('PotatoMapper.php');
$potato = new App_Model_Potato();
$potatoMapper = new App_Model_PotatoMapper();
$potatoMapper->eat($potato);
?>
EOF

cat > Model.php <<"EOF"
<?php
abstract class App_Model {
    protected $vegetable = False;
}
?>
EOF

cat > Mapper.php <<"EOF"
<?php
abstract class App_Mapper{
    public function eat(App_Model $cls) { 
        echo "App_Mapper->eat()\n";
    }
}
?>
EOF

cat > Potato.php <<"EOF"
<?php
require_once('Model.php');
class App_Model_Potato extends App_Model {
    protected $potato = True;
}
?>
EOF

cat > PotatoMapper.php <<"EOF"
<?php
require_once('Mapper.php');
class App_Model_PotatoMapper extends App_Mapper{
    public function eat(App_Model_Potato $cls){ 
        echo "App_Model_PotatoMapper->eat()\n";
    }
}
?>
EOF
```

When running the example, the notice generated is this:

```
# php doStuff.php
PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of App_Model_PotatoMapper::eat() should be
compatible with App_Mapper::eat(App_Model $cls) in /tmp/bs2/PotatoMapper.php
on line 3
```

The PotatoMapper's eat() function is:

```
public function eat(App_Model_Potato $cls)
```

And PotatoMapper extends the base Mapper class, whose eat() is this:

```
public function eat(App_Model $cls) { echo "App_Mapper->eat()\n";}
```

Does the example have anything inherently wrong with it?

How do I refactor this example to fix the notices?

Comment: Wow this question is incredably hard to read. Please edit to just include the full class definitions, followed by the calling code, and the error. Please remove the cli commands as they just add noise

Comment: But ultimatly the answer is ensure the method signature match, eg derivatives of `Mapper` should either not override `eat` method, or if they do, the method should typehint `App_Model`